# why sls aka select-string does not work

Tags: powershell

I am newbie on powershell. Today I tried something very simple

```
Alias  | sls -Pattern 'echo'
```

which produced `echo`, but what I want is `Alias echo -> Write-Out`.

In bash,  you can just do

```
alias | grep 'echo'
```

My question is why `sls` does not work. BTW, if I replace `sls` with `findstr`, it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get an alias with a particular name you can do:

```
alias -name echo
```

The `echo -> Write-Out` is the `DisplayName`:

```
(alias -name echo).DisplayName
```

The `Get-Alias` command returns a sequence of objects, each of which represents a single command alias. When displayed in powershell, these objects are formatted as a table containing the `CommandType`, `Name` and `ModuleName` properties.

When you pipe into `findstr`, it is the string representations of these columns which are being filtered, so any match displays the whole table row:

```
Alias           echo -> Write-Output
```

When you pipe into `Select-String` each object is being bound to the `-InputObject` parameter of the `Select-String` cmdlet. Since `Select-String` operates on text, it just calls `ToString` on the received object to get its string representation.

`ToString` only returns the `Name` property. You can see this by executing the following:

```
alias | %{$_.tostring()}
```

Therefore any matches from `Select-String` only match on the alias name.

Comment: `findstr` is a legacy app (used in cmd where commands use text-parsing). So when you pipeline the result into it, ps converts to strings and it processes it. powershell-cmdlets itself work on object-level. Usage in PS is explained above by Lee :)

Answer (score 4):

`select-string` only behaves like `grep` when used with a text file. With a powershell object, the behavior changes (as Lee explained in his answer).

This can be demonstrated with:

```
alias > out.txt; cat out.txt | sls -pattern 'echo'
```

Which returns `Alias echo -> Write-Output` because now `sls`is operating on a text file.

The other solutions to do what you want are:

1. `alias | where DisplayName -like '*echo*'`
2. `alias | out-string -stream | sls -pattern 'echo'`

   This converts the powershell object to a string so that `sls` works like `grep`.